# ボタン押下時に他のボタンを無効化したい

Tags: swift4

stopButtonを押した時に、nextButtonとbackButtomを無効化したいのですが、どのようにすれば良いですか？

```
IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if imageIndex == 2 {
        imageIndex = 0
    }else {
        imageIndex = imageIndex + 1
    }
    imageView.image = images[imageIndex]
}

@IBAction func backButtom(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.imageIndex == 0 {
        imageIndex = 2
    }else {
        imageIndex = imageIndex - 1
    }
    imageView.image = images[imageIndex]
}

@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(self.movePhoto(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***nextButtonとbackButtomを無効化したいのですが、どのようにすれば良いですか？***

コードの一部しかご質問に掲載されていませんが、2つのボタンを表すoutlet変数は宣言して接続してあるでしょうか? もしまだでしたら、次のような宣言を追加して、storyboardエディター上でoutletとして接続しておいてください。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var theNextButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var theBackButton: UIButton!

    //...
}
```

※`ViewController`があなたの実際のクラス名と異なる場合には、適切に読み替えてください。

※`nextButton`や`backButton`という識別子がアクションメソッドの方に使われているので、かぶらないように`theNextButton`, `theBackButton`なんてしてしまいました。本当はメソッド名の方を「アクションメソッドっぽい名前」に変えた方が良いと思うのですが、一度接続されたアクションメソッドのメソッド名を変更すると、Xcodeのバグを踏んでしまうことがあるので、outlet名の方をいじりました。

この準備をしておけば、普通の`UIControl`の無効化は`isEnabled`プロパティの値を`false`にしてやるだけです。

```
@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(self.movePhoto(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    theNextButton.isEnabled = false
    theBackButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

お試しください。